# Passing value to \bibleverse

Tags: macros, xstring

Please help me to find out, how to pass a value to a command, which has additional arguments enclosed in (...).

```
\usepackage{bibleref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\bibleverse{Gen}(9:9)
\bibleverse{Gen}(\StrBehind{Gen 9:9}{Gen })
\end{document}
```

This gives an error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \@bibleverse was complete.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment occurring within `\StrBehind` is not expandable and therefore cannot be passed directly to `\bibleverse`. Moreover, the argument captured by `\bibleverse` (internally) won't be split properly if not fully expanded. You need to store the value first, and then pass an expanded version to `\bibleverse`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibleref,xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{bibleref,xstring}
\begin{document}
\bibleverse{Gen}(9:9)

\StrBehind{Gen 9:9}{Gen }[\chapverse]
\expandafter\bibleverse\expandafter{\expandafter G\expandafter e\expandafter n\expandafter}\expandafter(\chapverse)
\end{document}
```

`\StrBehind{<stringA>}{<stringB>}[<cmd>]` stores whatever follows `<stringB>` in `<stringA>` in `<cmd>`. Appropriately-placed `\expandafter`s ensure that `\chapverse` is expanded before parsing of the argument between parentheses of `\bibleverse` is performed.

Answer (score 3):

If your aim is to be able to specify only `\macro{Gen 9:9}` and format it as if you had written `\bibleverse{Gen}(9:9)`, then `xstring` is not needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibleref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shortbibleverse}[1]{\@shortbibleverse#1\@nil}
\def\@shortbibleverse#1 #2\@nil{\bibleverse{#1}(#2)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\bibleverse{Gen}(9:9)

\shortbibleverse{Gen 9:9}
\end{document}
```

Rename `\shortbibleverse` to your liking.

The macro works by splitting the argument at the (first) space, passing what's before as the mandatory argument to `\bibleverse` and what's after as the optional argument in parentheses.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a MWE.

Comment: I want to write something like bibleref-russian, and it will need a more detailed processing of the arguments.